# Testing for filtering state of selectors in Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

An example of the code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8zomm846v9

I'm writing a test for `selectors.js`. My fixture data is a section of the state being converted into an immutable map. From my understanding, as `makeSelectYears()` is called, it will execute `selectYearsDomain()` and return only the years. It will then return the filtered data as a JSON object.

However, `makeSelectYears().resultFunc(fixture)` returns the entire JSON without the filter. I have the output commented in the above link.

I'm not able to modify `selectors.js` in any way, only add testing. I'm 
 not sure the best way to test the selector to ensure it's working as intended.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
makeSelectYears().resultFunc(fixture)
```

you should call

```
makeSelectYears()(fixture)
```